# A circle passes through (-1,3) and (5,11) with radius 5. How do I go about finding its center?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

A circle passes through (-1,3) and (5,11) with radius 5. How do I go about finding its center?

I tried writing the equations but it became too complicated. Is there a simple way?

I tried
$x²+y²+2gx+2fy+c= 0$
Then
$c= g²+f²-r²$ but it ended up in complicated cases

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: $-1=5\cos(\phi_1)+\Delta x$,
$3=5\sin(\phi_1)+\Delta y$,  
$5=5\cos(\phi_2)+\Delta x$,
$11=5\sin(\phi_2)+\Delta y$ 

are four equations with four unknowns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the distance between the two given points is $\sqrt{(11-3)^2+(5-(-1))^2}=10$. This means that for a circle of radius $5$ to pass through them, it must have the segment between those two points as its diameter, and so its centre must be the midpoint, or $(2,7)$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the distance between two points is the diameter so the center is the midpoint.

Answer (score 2):

If the two points did not happen two be opposite each other on the circle, a more general way to solve this problem is to solve the system of equations:
$$(x_1-r_x)^2+(y_1-r_y)^2 = r^2$$
$$(x_2-r_x)^2+(y_2-r_y)^2 = r^2,$$
where the radius $r$ and two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are given.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it was getting lengthy and I was sure that this sum could be done in much less so I was trying to find some other way. I didn't notice that the distance between the points is the diameter.